# No media present error before Grub shows up

Tags: boot, grub2

When I power up my PC, a screen saying no media present shows up. After a while Grub menu shows up and I can boot Ubuntu. **I just want to know if there is a way to prevent the no media present error.** I only have Ubuntu installed in the HDD.

**My laptop:** Toshiba Satellite L50-A-1D4; HDD is changed, it has 300GBs of storage capacity.

*Sorry for any mistakes in text, I'm not a fluent English speaker.*

Comment: The "*No media present*" message will be caused by your machine *firmware* and thus the configuration of that will be machine specific (ie. not a Ubuntu question, as Ubuntu doesn't start until **after** grub has completed boot; grub being the bootloader that is started by your machine firmware)

Comment: Ah okay, didn't know about that. Thanks for the info.